# Bundle typescript and protobuf.js with tsify

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, browserify, tsify

I used the google API to generate a lib.js from a lib.proto. In Typescript I have used it with `declare var lib: any;`. My problem is that browserify ignores the lib.js because it's only a declaration.

Is there any way to add the lib.js at the right place to the bundle.js?

my tsify command:

```
browserify -p tsify src/main.ts > bundle.js
```

my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "removeComments": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

my hierarchy:

```
root
    src
        main.ts
        lib.proto
        lib.js
        lib.d.ts
    bundle.js
    index.html
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

statment:

```
declare var lib: any;
let p = lib.deserializeBinary(data);
```

[lib.d.ts](https://pastebin.com/3AhwVLFy)

Comment: I'm able to have `.js` files that have associated `.d.ts` files included in the bundle. Without including your configuration details (`tsconfig.json`, tsify options, directory structure, etc.) in the question, answering this is not going to be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you include your `import` statement and the `.d.ts`, too?

Comment: Updated. I do not have any import statement for this. For my it is only possible to import npm modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only declare the type of a `lib`. All module loaders will never bundle `lib` if you have never imported it.

Just place `require('./lib.js');`, before you use the `lib` variable. It should work.

Comment: require("lib.js") or require("lib") ends up with a browserify error: "Error: Cannot find module 'lib.js' from '/PATH/src'

Comment: I've forgotten about "./"